# How to find which fields in one table match criteria based on another

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a two tables: `sections` and `samples`.  I was just asked to add the ability to see whether any sections have samples associated with them.

In order to do this I need to use the fields `Job`, `ID`, and `SectionNumber` from the `samples` table and match them to the same fields on the `sections` table.

I also need to decide whether or not I should create a new field in `sections` called `hasSamples` and maintain it.

Sample data:

```
samples table:  `Job | ID | SectionNumber | Type | Tests`
      samples: `J1302, JC310, 2, Bag, Stress`
```

sections table:  `Job | ID | SectionNumber | Depth`

```
  sections: `J1301, JD493, 1, 128`
            `J1302, JC310, 2, 50`
```

Desired results could be something like this:

```
`Job | ID | SectionNumber | Samples` `J1302, JC310, 2, 1`
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and any attempts that you have made to solve this problem.

Comment: More advice: Please clarify whether the relationship between section and sample is 1 to 1, 1 to many, or many to many.  You mention a section hasSamples.  This seems to imply that there are many samples to one section.  If that is true, the query I gave you will return a row for every sample and also a row for any sections without samples.   You may want to GROUP BY section or something to consolidate.  It's hard to know without more info.

Comment: @TomHaws There are many samples to one section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sections se
LEFT JOIN samples sa ON sa.Job = se.Job AND sa.ID = se.ID, and sa.SectionNumber = sel.SectionNumber
WHERE sa.ID IS NOT NULL
```

In your initial design, there may be no compelling reason to have a "calculated" or "cached" field such as hasSamples, since the JOIN is apparently trivial (assuming you have all the correct indexes and foreign relationships properly defined).  But if you decided at some point that performance can be helped by avoiding a super frequent JOIN, there's no reason you can't add the column.

Comment: I suppose I did a poor job describing the problem.  There's another column that is a surrogate key, RID.  There can be several sections that share the same Job, ID, SectionNumber.  Running your query gives many results as it matches multiple sections.  I only need to match once.  In other words, I'd like to get a result such that for each unique Job, ID, SectionNumber from sections it gives me the number of samples that have a matching Job, ID, SectionNumber.

Comment: I'm actually using a very similar query of this in my solution.  The difference is that I only need the keys from both tables.  I tried using inner join, but left join turns out to be what I needed.  I also need the results including NULL, so I dropped the WHERE clause.

Comment: You may want to GROUP BY section or something to consolidate.

Comment: I did end up using a GROUP BY and a COUNT:  `SELECT se.RID, COUNT(sa.RID), sa.JobNumber, sa.CoreID, sa.SecNum FROM sectiontestings se LEFT JOIN samples sa ON se.jobnumber = sa.JobNumber AND se.coreid = sa.CoreID AND se.sectionnumber = sa.SecNum GROUP BY se.RID;`